# Simplifying and taking the limit

Tags: calculus, limits, exponentiation

I would like to compute the following limit $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{10^{n^{2}}}{10^{(n+1)^{2}}}$$
but I'm having a hard time simplifying. Can anyone explain to me the properties of these exponents?

Thanks

Comment: Rewrite your expression as $10^{n^2-(n+1)^2} = 10^{-2n-1}$, which can be made smaller than any positive value as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: $$10^{(n+1)^{2}} = 10^{n^2 + 2n + 1} = 10^{n^2} \cdot 10^{2n} \cdot 10^{1}$$

Answer (score 3):

Notice the following:

$\frac{10^{n^{2}}}{10^{(n+1)^{2}}}$=$\frac{10^{n^{2}}}{10^{n^2+2n+1}}$

$\frac{10^{n^{2}}}{10^{n^2+2n+1}}=\frac{10^{n^{2}}}{10^{n^2}10^{2n}10^{1}}$

$\frac{10^{n^{2}}}{10^{n^2}10^{2n}10^{1}}$=$\frac{1}{10^{2n+1}}$

So, I hope now, it should be obvious what happens as $n$ gets infinitely large.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** $$10^{(n+1)^2}=10^{n^2+2n+1}=10^{n^2}10^{2n+1}.$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{10^{n^{2}}}{10^{(n+1)^{2}}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{10^{n^{2}}}{10^{n^2}\cdot10^{2n+1}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{10^{2n+1}}=0$$

Answer (score 0):

First, you can simplify this fraction:
$$\frac{10^{n^2}}{10^{(n+1)^2}}=\frac{10^{n^2}}{10^{n^2+2n+1}}$$
Here, you can use the property of exponents which states:
$$\frac{a^m}{a^n}=a^{m-n}$$
Applying the property, we get:
$${10^{n^2-(n^2+2n+1)}}={10^{-(2n+1)}}=\frac1{10^{(2n+1)}}$$
When we input infinity, we get:
$$\frac1{10^{2\infty+1}}=\frac1{10^\infty}=\frac1\infty=0$$